# Python: hint input string from list

Tags: python-3.x

do you know if it is possible to hint a string from a list?
Here an example to explain this better. Thanks a lot!

```
def funct(name: str):
    # name has to be one of the following: ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie']

    #do something


funct(name= here it should hint the 3 options
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If directly under the function you have something like below it will display the part in triple quotation marks when you hover over the function with your cursor

```
def funct(name: str):
    '''name has to be one of the following: ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie']'''

    #do something
```

This works on many IDEs, I use vscode personally and it looks like this

[image: image of code with description over function]

Answer (score 1):

Annotations can be anything, also a sentence explaining what you expect:

```py
def func(name: "`name' should be 'Alpha', 'Bravo' or 'Charlie'."):
  """Function's annotation, such as:
`name' should be 'Alpha', 'Bravo' or 'Charlie'.
"""
  #do something
```